# using php variables in a html email using swiftmailer

Tags: php, html, swiftmailer

Im using swiftmailer to send my emails from my site. I'm trying to get a html email to send but i want to pass a php variable in to the email.

Is this possible and if so where am i going wrong?

```
->setBody(
    '<html>' .
    ' <head></head>' .
        ' <body>' .
    '  Welcome to my site. To complete registration, please click activate below' .
    '  <a href="http://www.mysite.com/activate.php?=c' rawurlencode ($code)' ">activate  ' .
    ' </body>' .
    '</html>',
    'text/html'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using this

```
<?php rawurlencode ($code);?>
```

unless than

`rawurlencode ($code)`

Comment: i was just thinking as it was html code i had to delcare the php tags to use a variable. oviously not. I have updated my code without that but cant seem to work out with its giving me a syntax error.

Comment: Of course you have to concat the string and that is

. rawurlencode ($code) .

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
->setBody(
    '<html>' .
    ' <head></head>' .
        ' <body>' .
    '  Welcome to my site. To complete registration, please click activate below' .
    '  <a href="http://www.mysite.com/activate.php?=c'. rawurlencode ($code) .' ">activate  ' .
    ' </body>' .
    '</html>',
    'text/html'
);
</pre>
```